# Getting the height of another element in pure CSS, Stylus or Nib

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, stylus

I want to implement a navbar using CSS

HTML

```
<nav>
    Navbar content
</nav>
<div id="mainContent">
    Main page
</div>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    position:fixed;
    height: X%;
    min-height: Ypx;
}

#mainContent {
    margin-top: Z; // where Z is the height of nav which is either X% or Ypx
}
```

I know a solution is to use *jQuery* but right now I am learning pure **CSS** and plan to continue with **Stylus** and **Nib** in Meteor.... **SO**... is there a CSS-esque solution?

Can you do some *computation* in the "stylesheet" to get height of other elements even if it requires Stylus?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calculate the height of the screen in pixels below which `min-height : Ypx;` works.

If height of screen H<((Y*100)/X)px then min-height will be the height of the navbar.

So, set the rules,

`#mainContent {
    margin-top: X%;}`

and also

```
`@media screen and (max-height:Hpx) {
#mainContent {
                 margin-top: Ypx;
             }
}
```

Where Hpx equals to previously calculated value ((Y*100)/X)px.

Therefore, normally margin-top will be X% , but if the height of screen goes below Hpx which triggers min-height, @media rule will be triggered, making margin-top equal to Ypx.